# How do I navigate to different categories with the same page grid but showing different data using Flutter Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im working on building a flutter application with dart.

I have these 5 classes that show list of products or “hot drinks” (Cappuccino and Americano..etc) and I want to also show a list of sweets (cookie, muffin..etc) that can be displayed when I click on the sweets section.

the code now only shows the hot drinks.

Here is the UI:

[Hot drinks category of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjegp.png)

1. Product class:

```
/// * The product identifier is an important concept and can have its own type.
typedef ProductID = String;

/// Class representing a product.
class Product {
  const Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
  });

  /// Unique product id
  final ProductID id;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Product(id: $id, imageUrl: $imageUrl, title: $title, description: $description, price: $price)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is Product &&
        other.id == id &&
        other.imageUrl == imageUrl &&
        other.title == title &&
        other.description == description &&
        other.price == price;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return id.hashCode ^
        imageUrl.hashCode ^
        title.hashCode ^
        description.hashCode ^
        price.hashCode;
  }
}
```

2. Product Gird class:

```
class ProductsGrid extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ProductsGrid({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final productsListValue = ref.watch(productsSearchResultsProvider);
    return AsyncValueWidget<List<Product>>(
      value: productsListValue,
      data: (products) => products.isEmpty
          ? Center(
              child: Text(
                'No products found'.hardcoded,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              ),
            )
          : ProductsLayoutGrid(
              itemCount: products.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                final product = products[index];
                return ProductCard(
                  product: product,
                  onPressed: () => context.goNamed(
                    AppRoute.product.name,
                    pathParameters: {'id': product.id},
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

3. Fake Repository class:

```
class FakeProductsRepository {
  FakeProductsRepository({this.addDelay = true});
  final bool addDelay;
  final List<Product> _products = kTestProducts;

  List<Product> getProductsList() {
    return _products;
  }

  Product? getProduct(String id) {
    return _getProduct(_products, id);
  }

  Future<List<Product>> fetchProductsList() async {
    await delay(addDelay);
    return Future.value(_products);
  }

  Stream<List<Product>> watchProductsList() async* {
    await delay(addDelay);
    yield _products;
  }

  Stream<Product?> watchProduct(String id) {
    return watchProductsList().map((_products) => _getProduct(_products, id));
  }

  static Product? _getProduct(List<Product> _products, String id) {
    try {
      return _products.firstWhere((_products) => _products.id == id);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<List<Product>> searchProducts(String query) async {
    assert(
      _products.length <= 100,
      'Client-side search should only be performed if the number of products is small. '
      'Consider doing server-side search for larger datasets.',
    );
    // Get all products
    final productsList = await fetchProductsList();
    // Match all products where the title contains the query
    return productsList
        .where((_products) =>
            _products.title.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
  }
}

final productsRepositoryProvider = Provider<FakeProductsRepository>((ref) {
  // * Set addDelay to false for faster loading
  return FakeProductsRepository(addDelay: false);
});

final productsListStreamProvider =
    StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<Product>>((ref) {
  final productsRepository = ref.watch(productsRepositoryProvider);
  return productsRepository.watchProductsList();
});

final productsListFutureProvider =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<Product>>((ref) {
  final productsRepository = ref.watch(productsRepositoryProvider);
  return productsRepository.fetchProductsList();
});

final productProvider =
    StreamProvider.autoDispose.family<Product?, String>((ref, id) {
  final productsRepository = ref.watch(productsRepositoryProvider);
  return productsRepository.watchProduct(id);
});

final productsListSearchProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose
    .family<List<Product>, String>((ref, query) async {
  final productsRepository = ref.watch(productsRepositoryProvider);
  return productsRepository.searchProducts(query);
});
```

4. Test Product class:

```
const kTestProducts = [
  Product(
      id: '1',
      imageUrl: 'assets/products2/cappuccino.png',
      title: 'Cappuccino',
      description: 'cappuccino ...',
      price: 15),
  Product(
      id: '2',
      imageUrl: 'assets/products2/americano.png',
      title: 'Americano',
      description: 'americano ...',
      price: 10),
  Product(
      id: '3',
      imageUrl: 'assets/products2/turkish.png',
      title: 'Turkish',
      description: 'turkish ...',
      price: 9),
];
```

5. Categories class:

```
class ProdcuctsCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProdcuctsCategory({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ProductsCategoryState();
}

class _ProductsCategoryState extends State<ProdcuctsCategory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              foregroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 118, 81),
              textStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('Hot Drinks'),
          ),
          gapW8,
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              foregroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(100, 113, 106, 106),
              textStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('Cold Drinks'),
          ),
          gapW8,
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              foregroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(100, 113, 106, 106),
              textStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('Sandwiches'),
          ),
          gapW8,
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              foregroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(100, 113, 106, 106),
              textStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('Sweets'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The grid shows the fake repository for the hot drinks but how do I build and differentiate the other categories (Cold drinks, sandwiches, sweets)

Comment: Add a product type parameter for your Product like Hot Drinks, Coffe, Sandwich, etc. & based on the product type filter the mock kProducts List & show data on TabBarView based on selected Tab Index